# Object nil unless I add another line of 'random' code

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, core-data, null

I think I might be going crazy. In the following method, the return value _persistentStoreCoordinator is nil **unless** I add another line of code. Checking `_persistentStoreCoordinator == nil` is enough to make sure that it isn't. (An NSLog statement will also do the trick.)

If I don't add another line, _persistentStoreCoordinator is nil in the last line of the method, even though when inspecting it with break-points `psc` is always non-nil.

The strangest (or perhaps most helpful?) thing is that I didn't make any changes to this class when the problems started.

Any help or explanations greatly appreciated!

```
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator {
    if (_persistentStoreCoordinator == nil) {
        NSLog(@"SQLITE STORE PATH: %@", [self pathToLocalStore]);
        NSURL *storeURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[self pathToLocalStore]];
        NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *psc = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc]
                                             initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
        NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                 [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption,
                                 [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption, nil];
        NSError *e = nil;
        if (![psc addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType
                               configuration:nil
                                         URL:storeURL
                                     options:options
                                       error:&e]) {
            NSDictionary *userInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:e forKey:NSUnderlyingErrorKey];
            NSString *reason = @"Could not create persistent store.";
            NSException *exc = [NSException exceptionWithName:NSInternalInconsistencyException
                                                       reason:reason
                                                     userInfo:userInfo];
            @throw exc;
        }

        _persistentStoreCoordinator = psc;
        if (_persistentStoreCoordinator == nil)
        {
            NSLog(@"We never reach here.");
        }
    }

    return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
}
```

Comment: Sometimes the debugger shows an object being nil when it acutally is not. In that case help yourself with nslogging it. You can directly log the object. NSLog ("myObject: %@",_persistentStoreCoordinator); Doing so you will at least see its address or nil.

Comment: Hi Hermann, thanks I tried that. Strangely enough, if I placed it like this:
 `...
    _persistentStoreCoordinator = psc;
    NSLog(@"myObject: %@",_persistentStoreCoordinator);
    }
  return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
}`

It worked. However, placing the same statement after the if statement finished:
`...
    _persistentStoreCoordinator = psc;
  }
  NSLog(@"myObject: %@",_persistentStoreCoordinator);
  return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
}`

ended up returning a null value.

Comment: In the OP you are saying if(){NSLog()} makes the return value not `nil`, and it stops working if you add another NSLog referring the object after it ?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. It stops working if I remove the NSLog() from that scope. Placing it just about the return statement has no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon rechecking my .h file I saw that I was maintaining a weak reference to _persistantStoreCoordinator.

```
@property (weak, nonatomic, readonly) NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator;
```

Sure enough, changing the reference to strong fixed things.